# React deployment to firebase using github actions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, firebase-hosting, github-actions

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

now this is the gtihub actions workflow it is executing build job without errors but in deployment there comes an error 
[this is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kot17.png)
the error its shows is Error: Specified public directory 'build' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site landing-page-design-1 i have followed the blog from where the workflow is copied i did everything same except some of my project details which is obvious please help me out why is this error occuring and how can i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably unpacking artifact to root directory instead of `build/`.
I'm guessing article was written for `download-artifact@v1` while you are using `download-artifact@v2` (as that's where `master` points currently). Difference between both is discussed [here](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact#compatibility-between-v1-and-v2).

I'd verify first what is going on after artifact is downloaded

```yaml
- name:  Display directory structure
  run:   ls -R
  shell: bash
```

If files are indeed in root directory, adding `path` should fix that.

```yaml
- name: Download Artifact
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
  with:
   name: build
   path: build
```

PS: Using `actions/<name>@master` is not recommended, as it can always lead to issues if same action behaves differently between versions... for example `actions/download-artifact` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use [firebase-publish-react](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/firebase-publish-react) to simplify your workflow file

This particular action plugin takes care of building the application internally and also can reuse the build directory from previous steps.

```yaml
- name: Deploy to Firebase
  uses: mohammed-atif/firebase-publish-react@v1.0
  with:
    firebase-token: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```